# Limit LEFT JOIN results to 1 with flexible where clause

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

my query looks like that:

```
SELECT 
count(users.id)
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN mail_sender_jobs_actions ON mail_sender_jobs_actions.userID = users.id
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.userID = users.id
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.userID = users.id
WHERE {$flexibleWhereClause}
```

Now, the mail_sender_jobs_actions table CAN (doesnt need to return anything) return multiple entries. I dont want to group the results but still limit the returns of mail_sender_jobs_actions to 1 so I dont get duplicates... Otherwise the count wouldnt work properly.

Scraped the whole web and found nothing working for me as I want to keep the where clause flexible. Any solution?

EDIT

so to explain the situation. We have a table with users (users). We have a table with actions (mail_seder_jobs_actions). We have other tables related to that query which are not relevant (table1, table2, table3)

If a user does an action, an entry is being created in the actions table.

The where clause is flexible, meaning it is possible that somebody wants to only show users with a specific action.

It is also possible that an action is not relevant to the user, so this entry gets ignored.

Comment: Does it mean you just want the first result of the query?

Comment: No, it returns a bunch of users. But right now it returns duplicates for the same user as the userID appears multiple times in the mail_sender_jobs_actions table...

Comment: So you want 1 row per user? If so, you have to group

Comment: But as I wrote, group doesnt work with count so this issue is left

Comment: I'm not sure what you want.  Do you want a count of the number of jobs per user?  What are table 2 and table 3 and what do they have to do with the information you want?  I think you need to sit down and have a think about exactly what it is you want to get, and why you want to get it.

Comment: okay so to explain the situation. We have a table with users (users). We have a table with actions (mail_seder_jobs_actions). We have other tables related to that query which are not relevant (table1, table2, table3)

If a user does an action, an entry is being created in the actions table.

The where clause is flexible, meaning it is possible that somebody wants to only show users with a specific action.

It is also possible that an action is not relevant to the user, so this entry gets ignored.

Answer (score 0):

1. With where criteria you have there is no point using left join, since the where criteria applies to the table on the right hand side, effectively turning the left join into an inner join.
2. Apparently yo do not use any columns from the right hand side table, so instead of using joins, I would use an [exists subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).

   `SELECT 
   1 as count,
   users.email
   FROM users
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM mail_sender_jobs_actions
                 WHERE mail_sender_jobs_actions.userID = users.id
                 AND mail_sender_jobs_actions.type = '1' 
                 AND mail_sender_jobs_actions.jobID = '106' 
                 AND {$flexibleWhereClause})`

However, there is little point in having the count() because it will always return 1. If you want to count how many records each user has in the `mail_sender_jobs_actions` table, then you have to use left join, group by, and move the where criteria into the join condition:

```
SELECT 
count(mail_sender_jobs_actions.userID),
users.email
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN mail_sender_jobs_actions ON mail_sender_jobs_actions.userID = users.id
AND mail_sender_jobs_actions.type = '1' 
AND mail_sender_jobs_actions.jobID = '106' 
AND {$flexibleWhereClause}
GROUP BY users.email
```

Comment: but that requires the entry to exist in mail_sender_jobs_actions.
I still want to return a result eventhough there is no entry of this user in mail_sender_jobs_actions.

edit: Removed the mail_sender_jobs_actions where clauses, as they are kept flexible for this query.

Comment: See my updated answer. Next time pls make the question clearer.

Comment: @Shadow It's best not to answer questions if you're not clear on what the OP is actually asking, it's better to ask the OP for clarification.

Comment: hey, but the count should be on the users table because the user is not neccessarily in the actions table...

Comment: I know that moving the where clause into the join would be logical, but the where clause is flexible and not only related to the mail_sender_jobs_actions table. Thats why the where clause need to stay at the end...

Comment: 1) If the count is on the users table, then it will always return at least 1, even if there are no matches in the other table(s) for that particular users. It is pointless. 2) I understand that it would be a lot easier to dynamically assemble a query if you only needed to change the end of the query. Unfortunately, to achieve what you want within mysql, the criteria have to be moved into the join clause.

Comment: @GordonM I though I understood the question. Don't tell me it never happened to you that you misunderstood one.